# Subview frame not moving with View Controller

Tags: ios, uikit, frame, viewcontroller

I have a view controller and, offscreen to the left, I have a menu view that is only visible when the entire view controller view moves to the right 250px.

Here are some screenshots to better visualize the situation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj9mi.jpg

Initializing the menu view's frame:

```
menuView.frame = CGRect(x: -250,y: 0, width: 500, height: view.frame.height)
```

Animating the slide to reveal the menu view:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
    self.view.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.origin.x + 250
}, completion: nil)
```

Now, I have gesture recognizers on each label (e.g. "Profile"), but none of their selectors are triggered because the menu view's frame is left behind when the whole view controller slides to the right.

Is there a smarter way to do this menu "slide" effect? Or am I missing something right in front of me?

Thank you.